# Зависание при обновлении данных

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть `ListBox`. Он связывается через биндинг с неким свойством `public List<string> Items`.

```
public List<string> Items
{
    get
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        var res = new List<string>
        {
            "qqq",
            "www",
            "eee"
        };
        return res;
    }
}
```

Есть кнопочка для обновления данных

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
}
```

Как видно, при обновлении источника данных основной поток подвисает на 5 секунд. Как этого красиво избежать? Понятно, что запрашивать данные надо в другом потоке, но как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете в свойствах биндинга выставить [`IsAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx), в этом случае запрос значения будет происходить асинхронно:

```
ItemSource={Binding Items, IsAsync=True}
```

Но вообще по гайдлайну предполагается, что получение значение свойства не должно занимать много времени. Лучше сделать отдельный метод, который инициализирует данные, а свойство `Items` будет возвращать уже готовый список.

Или можно сделать загрузку непосредственно по клику кнопки. Пример загрузки по каждому клику (можно переделать ее на разовую, в зависимости от вашей задачи):

```
public List<string> Items { get; set; }

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.IsEnabled = false;
    try
    {
        // если ваш метод загрузки сам является асинхронным,
        // достаточно будет написать await LoadData()
        Items = await Task.Run(() => LoadData);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: уведомите пользователя об ошибке
    }
    finally
    {
        button.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}

private List<string> LoadData()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    var res = new List<string>
    {
        "qqq",
        "www",
        "eee"
    };
    return res;
}
```

Comment: `Но вообще по гайдлайну предполагается, что получение значение свойства не должно занимать много времени. Лучше сделать отдельный метод, который инициализирует данные, а свойство Items будет возвращать уже готовый список.` Ну тогда дополните ответ этим решением, пожалуйста

Comment: @iRumba это решение зависит от уже существующего кода. В любом случае метод инициализации должен вызываться после создания объекта (форма/вью модель) и должен завершаться до привязки свойства.

Comment: Я вам код в вопросе привел. На его примере предложите. Просто вы дали ответ и тут же сказали, что он не кошерный. )

Comment: @iRumba обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, забыл только сказать что проект на 4 фрэймворке, а в нем нет эвэйт и эсинк (

Comment: @iRumba если есть возможность, можете подключить https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/. Или обернуть загрузку в `BackgroundWorker` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx).